# Numpy and Scipy matrix inversion functions differences

Tags: numpy, scipy

My question is rather simple : What is the difference between the `numpy.linalg.inv` and the `scipy.linalg.inv` functions for matrices inversion

Is the Scipy function just a wrapper of the Numpy one ?
Efficiency, numerical stability, speed ... which one should I prefer ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the SciPy Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html) you get the following information:

> **scipy.linalg vs numpy.linalg**
>   `scipy.linalg` contains all the functions in `numpy.linalg`. plus some other more advanced ones not contained in `numpy.linalg`
>   Another advantage of using `scipy.linalg` over `numpy.linalg` is that it is always compiled with BLAS/LAPACK support, while for `numpy` this is optional. Therefore, the `scipy` version might be faster depending on how `numpy` was installed.
>
> Therefore, unless you don’t want to add `scipy` as a dependency to your `numpy` program, use `scipy.linalg` instead of `numpy.linalg`

I hope this helps!